# jQuery script not working after .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, merge

I have 4 pages "merged" to one (index.html) by load:

```
<!-- !!!! Files includes !!!! -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
$("#included1").load("aaa.html");
$("#included2").load("bbb.html");
$("#included3").load("ccc.html");
$("#included4").load("ddd.html");
});
</script>
```

and displayed here:

```
<div id="content">
<section><br>
<div id="included1"></div>
</section>
<section><br>
<div id="included2"></div>
</section>
<section><br>
<div id="included3"></div>
</section>
<section><br>
<div id="included4"></div>
</section>
</div>  <!-- end of content // text below menu-->
```

Unfortunately it has to be done that way due to some server restrictions and the fact, that those 4 pages are generated by script on different hours.

Inside code of each page there are MANY blocks with long text to be hidden/show on some action. It looks like this:

```
<div class="error">
<div class="more">[... more]</div>
<div id="edetails" class="content small">
Error code///Error code///Error code///Error code///Error code///Error code///
Error code///Error code///Error code///Error code///Error code///Error code///
Error code///Error code///Error code///Error code///Error code///Error code///
</div>
</div><!-- end of error -->
```

For that I use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.more').click(function () {
    if($(this).html()=="[... more]") {  
            $(this).html("[... less]");
            $(this).next('#edetails').removeClass('small');
            $(this).next('#edetails').addClass('normal');
    } else {  
            $(this).html("[... more]");
            $(this).next('#edetails').removeClass('normal');
            $(this).next('#edetails').addClass('small');
        };
});
});
</script>
```

If I keep that code on each page, and open that page (aaa.html for example, not index.html) - it works just fine.

If I open index.html - it doesn't work at all.

So... due to the fact, that I marge that code 4 times to index.html, I decided to move it once to index and keep it in `<head>` - and in the effect, when I open that page on my server - show/hidde function doesn't work at all.

BUT when I save index.html to my hard drive and open it in browser - IT WORKS AS IT SHOULD.

I don't know what's going on... Any ideas?

Comment: `$(window).load` being fired before the async `$('#included').load` are finished maybe ? Try using the `complete` parameter of `$('#included').load()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky part here is that `jQuery.load()` is asynchronous. You need to synchronize your calls in order to be able to run your script at correct time. I would suggest usage of `jQuery.Deferred` for that purpose:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function deferredLoad(target, url) {
        return $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
            $(target).load(url, function() {
                deferred.resolve();
            });
        }).promise();
    }

    var loadPromises = [];

    loadPromises.push(deferredLoad('#included1', 'aaa.html'));
    loadPromises.push(deferredLoad('#included2', 'bbb.html'));
    loadPromises.push(deferredLoad('#included3', 'ccc.html'));
    loadPromises.push(deferredLoad('#included4', 'ddd.html'));

    $.when.apply(null, loadPromises).done(function() {
        $('.more').click(function () {
            if($(this).html() == "[... more]") {  
                $(this).html("[... less]");
                $(this).next('#edetails').removeClass('small');
                $(this).next('#edetails').addClass('normal');
            } else {  
                $(this).html("[... more]");
                $(this).next('#edetails').removeClass('normal');
                $(this).next('#edetails').addClass('small');
            };
        });
    });
});
```

This way your script will be run when all the load operations will finish.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that I don't know how to use that. I placed that code inside <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> brackets just after jQuery implementation - all between <head> and </head>, and in the results I have blank page...

Comment: @BlackHat I will recheck if I haven't made any typos, can you please let me know which version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: It's jQuery v1.10.2; but - first things first, have I placed code right?

Comment: @BlackHat The place you have choosen is one of correct ones - do you have any JavaScript error in your console?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem so. At least in FF/Web Console. All I have done was to change names of files (for some security reasons).

Comment: @BlackHat I have updated the answer with wrapping everything into `$(document).ready()` event just be sure that the DOM is ready. Please test it now.